# Show header only on shoppage Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, header

Took me some time to find out a working code to show the header above the sidebar.
But I now have the problem that I just want to show the header on the shop-page and not on the product pages.
So I'm trying to figure out what do I need to change?

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content','before_main_content');

function before_main_content() { ?

<img src="image url">

<?php
}
?
```

Thank you guys for all the answers :)
This one worked for me :

```
function before_main_content() { 
if (is_shop()) { 
?>
<img src="image url">

<?php
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace *** with your shop page name:

```
<?php 
    if ( is_page('***')) { 
        **Insert your header code here**; 
    } 
?>
```

This works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the page conditional, `is_page()`, to determine if you should show the image. WooCommerce has a function to get the shop page ID. Test for it and return if it's not a match.

Example:

```
function wpse_before_main_content() { // before_main_content could be problematic, choose a prefix.

    // Check if we're on the shop page.
    if ( ! is_page( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) ) {
        return false;
    } ?>

    <img src=". . .

    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'wpse_before_main_content' );
```